# Finitely additive probability measure thats not countably subadditive

Tags: probability, measure-theory, probability-theory

How is it that a finitely additive probability measure on a field may not be countably subadditive?  I know that the field must be countably additive and thus finite additivity does not suffice, but I'm struggling with the reasoning.

Comment: What do you mean by "the field must be countably additive"?

Answer (score 4):

**Revised:** Let $\mathscr{F}=\{A\subseteq\Bbb N:A\text{ is finite or }\Bbb N\setminus A\text{ is finite}\}$, and define $\mu(A)=0$ if $A$ is finite and $\mu(A)=1$ if $\Bbb N\setminus A$ is finite.

Comment: Keeping in mind that I'm reading chapter 3 of my first measure theoretic probability text, could you be a bit more specific?

Comment: For each $A\subseteq\Bbb R$ set $\mu(A)=0$ if there is some $x>0$ such that $A\subseteq[-x,x]$ and $\mu(A)=1$ otherwise. Check that this is finitely additive. Then set $A_n=[-n,n]$ for $n\in\Bbb N$, and consider whether $\mu$ is countably subadditive.

Comment: I doesn't seem that such a measure would be a probability measure. If A is the interval from 1 to infinity and B from -1 to -infinity  the measure of their union would be 1 while the sum of both would be 2...

Comment: @rmh52: Yes, it needs to be defined a little more carefully than I thought at first. Try the revised example instead; it avoids that problem.

Comment: is script F supposed to be a sigma algebra?

Comment: @lithiumbarbiedoll: Of course not: it obviously isn’t one. The question doesn’t ask for one.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott StackExchange questions also serve a purpose as a knowledge center for future reference. The brevity of your answer and its unscrupulous edit make it of little value in this context.

Comment: @someperson $A = \{2n : n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ doesn't appear to be a member of $\mathscr{F}$, because neither $A$ nor $\mathbb{N} \setminus A$ are finite.  Perhaps I'm missing something.

Comment: I'll clarify my comment (which I inadvertently deleted). If A_n =: {2n}, for n in N, then A_n is in script(F) (since A_n is finite) but the union of the A_n, for n in N, isn't in script(F). So, script(F) isn't a sigma algebra as has been previously mentioned. Banach solved this problem using the Axiom of Choice.

Comment: @Sebastiaan: It says as much as is necessary to answer the question. There is nothing unscrupulous about an edit that improves the answer and, if substantive, is clearly noted.

Answer (score 1):

Examples of measures which cannot be extended to be countably summable are:
1) a uniform distribution on the rational numbers in the interval $[0,1]$.
This is easy to see: There are only countably many rationals, so any finite set of rationals will have measure zero (or the total probability will be infinite), yet
all of them together have measure 1. This is inconsistent with countable additivity.

2) a uniform distribution on the integers, by the same argument, sinvce any finite interval of inyegers must have probability zero.

More interesting: On some set of increasing sequences of natural numbers, define the density to be the limit (if it does not exist, take the limsup) of
$$
   \#\{n_k \colon n_k\le N\} / N
$$
when $N$ goes to infinity. It can be shown that density defined in this way is onlyn a finitely additive measure, cannot be extended to countably additive.

Comment: What do you mean by "a uniform distribution on the integers"?

Comment: well, let us reformulate to "uniform on the natural numbers 0,1,2,3 ..."..  Then, a subset such as the even numbers would have probability 1/2, $\{0,3,6,\dots \}$ would have probability 1/3, etc. for this distribution all finite subsets must have probability zero.

Comment: You should be more careful about stating explicitly what sets you're allowing to be "measurable" here.

Comment: Certainly, but I wrote a comment and not a thesis ... Anyhow, I don think measurability is such a problem with only finitely additive measures?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen Measurability is not a big problem if you are willing to extend a finitely additive measure using the Hahn-Banach theorem. But it prevents you from explicitely constructing a canonical finitely additive measure on a $\sigma$-algebra that is not countably additive.